# Write one value at a time

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I'm trying to write into a file the total acceleration from onSensorChanged( ) method. There is something wrong into my code that handle writing into the file. 
My file is showing only one value. I want to see **all** the values until I toggle my button to stop writing. Could you please indicate where is the wrong in my code. Thanks in advance.

```
 ToggleButton OnStore;   
 private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     OnStore = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.onStore);
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensor);
    accelermeter = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.registerListener(this, accelermeter, 
                 SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

     OnStore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (OnStore.isChecked()){
                String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                    File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File dir = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath()+"/MyApp");
                    if (!dir.exists()){
                        dir.mkdir();
                    }
                    File file = new File(dir,"Mymessage.txt");
                    try {
                        fileOutputStream  = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
                        String space =" ";
                        byte[] convert = space.getBytes();
                        fileOutputStream.write(convert);
                        String finalData;
                        finalData = String.valueOf(TotalAccelerate);
                        fileOutputStream.write(finalData.getBytes());
                        //fileOutputStream.close();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message saving",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SDcard not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            if (!OnStore.isChecked()){
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message Stopped.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });


  double TotalAccelerate;
  ArrayList<Double> list;

 @Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // The light sensor returns a single value.
    // Many sensors return 3 values, one for each axis.
    double xx = event.values[0];
    double yy = event.values[1];
    double zz = event.values[2];

    TotalAccelerate = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xx, 2)
            + Math.pow(yy, 2)
            + Math.pow(zz, 2)));
    // Log.i(DEBUG,"Total "+ TotalAccelerate);
    list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    list.add(TotalAccelerate);

    //  findPeaks(list);
    sensorText.setText("Total: " + list);
    Log.i(DEBUG, "Total " + list);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reinitialize your `list` every time in `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)`

you must do it in `onCreate` or after `if (OnStore.isChecked()){` to show all results between start and stop

**UPDATE**

add line `list = new ArrayList<Double>();` in `onClick(View view)`

```
     OnStore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (OnStore.isChecked()){
                list = new ArrayList<Double>();
                ...
```

and remove `list = new ArrayList<Double>();` in `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)`

**UPDATE 2**

add line `list = new ArrayList<Double>();` in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` instead `onClick(View view)`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ...
```

all your values are in `list`

```
for(double TotalAccelerate : list){
    System.out.println(TotalAccelerate);
}
```

Comment: I still didn't get it. Could you please write a code for illustration please.

Comment: It works, but I need to have all the values of **TotalAccelerate ** when my OnStore.isChecked. How can I do that. I feel I need a thread.

Comment: I mean I want all the values stored in my .txt file. I still didn't get it.